# What does adding `_text` to the end of a Rails model attribute do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at a Model that has attributes `some_id` and `owner`.

In console, I can see that `Model.first.some_id` is `:foo` and `Model.first.owner` is `:bar`. But when I enter `Model.first.some_id_text`, I get `1a2b3c4d5` while entering `Model.first.owner_text` gives me `"bar"`.

Where can I see how this transformation is being done? I tried looking up `some_id_text` and `owner_text` but found nothing.

Comment: When I try it, I get an error message. I think you must have a gem installed that adds that functionality to your models

Answer (score 1):

Those `_text` suffix methods might be add by some gems like `https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize` or similar things.

It loop your columns, and add dynamic method, `colum`_text methods.

You should paste your gems, and the model files.